# How can I return a value from a resolver in AWS Appsync?

Tags: graphql, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I have a Graph in with this as part of the Schema.

```
type Project {
  id: ID!
  card: String
  ....
}
```

I am trying to create a card resolver like this

```
  const projectCardResolverFunction = new AppsyncFunction(scope, 'projectCardResolverFunction', {
    name: 'projectCardResolverFunction',
    api,
    dataSource: graphqlDataSource,
    runtime: FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
    code: Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'project-resolver/index.ts')),
  });

  new Resolver(scope, 'projectCardResolver', {
    api,
    typeName: 'Project',
    fieldName: 'card',
    code: Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'project-resolver/passthrough.ts')),
    runtime: FunctionRuntime.JS_1_0_0,
    pipelineConfig: [projectCardResolverFunction],
  });
```

Here is the resolver code

```
// project-resolver/index.ts

export function request(ctx) {
  console.log('this is the request');
  // return 'This is the request';
  return 'This is the request';
}

export function response(ctx) {
  console.log('this is the response');
  return ctx.result;
}
```

I am expecting to return `This is the request` from the call to the Graph. Instead I get this error

```
"message": "Expected JSON object but got STRING instead."
```

1. What is the JSON object that is expected?
2. What are the expected keys and values?
3. Where can I find the documentation on how this would be done? I have looked in the docs and don't see anything clear.

Comment: What is the type of your data source?
The return value of the `request` function is sent to that data source (DynamoDB or Lambda, for example).